# Cheap chinese rice lights

Tags: lighting

I was shocked to see how cheap the chinese rice lights are! They even come with a controller attached with them, which allows you to change the lighting pattern.

[image]

I wanted to know what could they have used inside the controller box to make it cheap as well as functional at the same time. I opened the box and found nothing but few resistors, transistors, capacitor, diode, a push button and a "chip".

[image]

source: YouTube

I do not understand, what this chip may be and how's it controlling the lighting pattern. It doesn't have any transformer so I think this chip couldn't be a microcontroller. Then what could be this chip, that's powered by AC mains, and controlls as well as powers the light bulbs?

Comment: *" It doesn't have any transformer so I think this chip couldn't be a microcontroller."* Where did that conclusion come from?

Comment: It's from my limited knowledge of the subject. I have never heard a microcontroller working with AC supply! Is that a wrong notion of mine?

Comment: I was assuming this would run of batteries but if not there are other methods to get from line voltage to 5V or 12V. There might be a dedicated chip because the volume of these lights is high enough to design an ASIC.

Comment: Can a controller, 220VAC to 12VDC voltage convertor all be integrated in the same chip?

Comment: Most of these use a step down transformer. Does yours? | Low voltage controllers can contril small SCRs or TRIACs.

Comment: You are asking for too much to be deduced from a blurry picture. The device doesn't have to convert 220 VAC to 12 VDC all it needs to do is provide the required pulses of unidirectional current. Obviously what you have is doing that. Is it doing it safely and reliably; who knows. I am voting to close the question as too broad.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm sure it uses a capacitive dropper for the power supply. Cheap, no transformer needed, questionably safe.

Comment: I respect the concern of the members who say this is too broad question. Any suggestion then how to ask such questions in case they arise?

Comment: @Bhuvnesh It would be a REALLY good idea if you could answer questions asked. I KNOW that you said 220VAC to 12 VDC BUT it is very common for people to ask such questions but somehow miss out the fact that a transfomer is present. I would be surprised if I could not deduce the means of operation given enough information (((look at my answer record))), but it helps to be sure what the real question is. | You say 12VDC - why? Did you measure 12VDC, or infer it or ...? ||  A properly focused photo would "be nice" and one of the others side of the PCB would also be useful. ...

Comment: ...I do not see components there which suggest direct 230 VAC conversion to 12VDC, but, it is possible. A phase angle controlled SCR may allow this. I recently dismantled a continuously variable electric blanket controller - they were using a TO92 TRIAC for load control. | There is a "trick" whereby you use eg a high voltage transistor which is tuned on only when the AC mains cycle is below some Vmax. Very clever and at great risk of "things going wrong". (Similar to phase control). Answers to questions asked will help you and me both learn something.

Comment: @Hearth There seems to be no mains dropper cap in the conventional sens. Spehro's answer seems more likely correct. ie a whisper of LV to the controller and mains voltage phase angle control of the LEDs by SCR or TRIAC. OR a low voltage transformer.

Comment: @Bhuvnesh PLEASE advise - is there a stepdown transformer or do these really plug directly into the mains with no transformer?

Comment: @Russell McMahon There's no transformer. It plugs directly into the mains without any transformer!

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Very clever. Very lethal. Spehro's answer is likely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely it's a CMOS ASIC, though a microcontroller is also possible (they're available from about 3 cents each packaged and that one is COB so potentially cheaper)

The parts would be a capacitive or resistive dropper power supply to get something like 5V at perhaps a few tens or hundreds of uA for the chip to run on (though I don't see the large film capacitor typically used for capacitive droppers so maybe it's just a 1/4-W resistor).

The output device would not be on-chip- probably something like a TO-92 2N5064 SCR which requires only a brief pulse of a few hundred uA to turn on. Add a series resistor to the chip- maybe that 3M\$\Omega\$ one- to provide zero-crossing detection and you have a workable system for a few ¥ (CNY). Looks like it's supplying half-wave to the lights, so probably flicker-y even at 60Hz and worse again at 50Hz.

Nothing, including the output to the lights, is isolated from the mains, so you have to assume any point in the circuit is a potentially lethal shock hazard. It may also be a fire hazard- I don't see a fuse. Check to see if it has appropriate safety agency approval for use in your country (such as CSA or UL) and a legitimate file number that can be verified.

Comment: Likely about right IF it really uses mains AC input. A "clever trick" overall and liable to be lethally dangerous given the construction.